# In GLSL, is it better to branch, or look up from a dummy texture?

Tags: opengl, optimization, glsl

To make a long story short, am I better off doing this:

```
if (normalMappingEnabled)
{
    normal = calculateBumpedNormalFromTexture();
}
else
{
    normal = somethingMuchEasierToCalculate();
}
```

Where normalMappingEnabled is a uniform, calculateBumpedNormalFromTexture requires a texture lookup and all of the other math required for normal mapping, and somethingMuchEasierToCalculate requires no texture lookup, and simply spits out the interpolated per-vertex normal.

or this:

```
normal = calculateBumpedNormalFromTexture();
```

Where in this case, if I don't need normal mapping, the normal texture is 1x1, containing a single texel that points straight up, producing the same result as if I had just used an interpolated per-vertex normal.

Which is faster on most modern hardware?  Is there another solution I haven't considered (other than using 2 different shaders)?

Answer (score 2):

If the condition is the same for all invocated fragments, then no branch divergence will happen. So AFAIK in this case, there will be no performance loss.

The problem is when some threads need to execute one branch and some threads the other branch. Since different instructions can't be executed in parallel (on one processor), both branches would be executed sequentially (some threads would get executed, the other part would wait and then the other part would get executed and the first part would wait).

Comment: The condition (normalMappingEnabled) would only change in between draw calls - it's a uniform variable.

Comment: Yes - as I've said, in this case, there should be no performance loss.

Comment: Thank you, that's very good to know.  Does that also apply to switch statements and loops?  How about using uniform buffer objects?

Comment: The principal is the same - if all the threads (fragments) do exactly the same, it's OK. But loops always have some additional overhead, so it's a bit different. It's always good to avoid loops if possible.

Comment: But checking condition have some cost too. Correct answer should be like "try both and measure".

Comment: The only problem with "try both and measure" is that what's faster on my hardware might not be faster on someone else's.

Comment: "if" costs a lot if it's used for GLSL of OpenGL ES. I will prefer to avoid "if" in shader which is controlled by uniform.